# Is there a way to retrieve user settings from a corrupt VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code 1.27.2 on Windows 10.

**Background:**

Recently there was an issue in the system not related to VS, and I had to run system repair which seems to have messed up with the settings of various programs, including VS.

**Current situation:**

Now when I open VS I get this:

[title bar of VS with 'Unsupported' at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlMMh.png)

[warning: "Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQhRZ.png)

According to the [official FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported), this can be due to fishy extensions. But this seems unlikely given that the last extension I installed was more than a week before this incident, and more importantly because of the system-wide settings shake-up.

**Main issue:**

When I try to access settings directly, I get another strange error:

[warning: "Unable to open 'User Settings': e.replace is not a function (2 errors in total)."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Ztn.png)

This function didn't look familiar so I looked it up and it was in the doxygen code, which has not changed for weeks, so also don't think this is the real issue.

I tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031023/where-are-the-visual-studio-settings-stored) but there was nothing found in my folders.

I plan on re-installing in all cases. It's not the end of the world if the settings are gone, but it would be great to ensure they are saved because I spent a lot of trial and error customizing them.

Comment: **Update**: I uninstalled VS Code and it said before confirming that settings will not be deleted. After installing the new version, everything was just how I left it including my settings. Woohoo. They must have been somewhere on my system then, just not sure where. Or they could be stored somehow online.